# Creating a next button that will pull from a text file

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I created a quiz that uses a text file to pull questions from. I don't know how to run through all the questions. I think that if I were to create an int that would increase every time someone would select a question until they run through them all would work. How would I create the int that would increase with each question and implement a next button. The way that the quiz is set up is on one view controller it has a label that changes to the first line of text in the text file and four buttons that will change to the next four lines. Once a button is selected and the correct process to note whether it was correct or not runs, which in turn hides the four buttons and displays a label with the last line (which is stopped by a * in the text file to indicate that it is the correct answer). Right now I can only get it to run the first question in each text file. The int method is the only way I can think that would work, but I am open to other ideas. Thank you very much! I have slowly found a way to get the quiz to work and as soon as I do I will post it to github so that people who have been following this will see how I have everything.

```
- (void)loadFirstCategory {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FirstVolume"
                                                     ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                     error:NULL];
    NSArray *lines = [content componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
    // Line is going to have @[Question, Answer, ..., * Correct Answer]

    NSMutableArray *questionAnswers = [NSMutableArray array];

    BOOL loadedQuestion = NO;

    QuestionAnswer *questionAnswer = [QuestionAnswer new];

    for(NSString *line in lines) {
        if(!loadedQuestion) {
            loadedQuestion = YES;
            questionAnswer.question = line;
            continue;
        }

        if([line isEqualToString:@""]) {
            [questionAnswers addObject:questionAnswer];
            questionAnswer = [QuestionAnswer new];
            loadedQuestion = NO;
            continue;
        }

        NSString *firstCharacter = [line substringToIndex:1];

        if([firstCharacter isEqualToString:@"*"]) {
            NSString *correctAnswer = [line substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, line.length - 2)];
            questionAnswer.rightAnswer = correctAnswer;
            continue;
        } else {
            [questionAnswer.possibleAnswers addObject:line];
            continue;
        }
    }

    QuestionAnswer *tempQuestionAnswer = [questionAnswers objectAtIndex:0];

    QuestionText.text = tempQuestionAnswer.question;

    [Answer1 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [Answer2 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [Answer3 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [Answer4 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    if(tempQuestionAnswer.possibleAnswers.count >= 1) {
        [Answer1 setTitle:[tempQuestionAnswer.possibleAnswers objectAtIndex:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    if(tempQuestionAnswer.possibleAnswers.count >= 2) {
        [Answer2 setTitle:[tempQuestionAnswer.possibleAnswers objectAtIndex:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    if(tempQuestionAnswer.possibleAnswers.count >= 3) {
        [Answer3 setTitle:[tempQuestionAnswer.possibleAnswers objectAtIndex:2] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    if(tempQuestionAnswer.possibleAnswers.count >= 4) {
        [Answer4 setTitle:[tempQuestionAnswer.possibleAnswers objectAtIndex:3] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    CorrectAnswerDisplay.text = tempQuestionAnswer.rightAnswer;

    NSInteger indexOfCorrectAnswer = 0;

    for(NSString *possibleAnswer in tempQuestionAnswer.possibleAnswers) {
        if([possibleAnswer isEqualToString:tempQuestionAnswer.rightAnswer]) {
            break;
        }

        indexOfCorrectAnswer++;
    }

    if(indexOfCorrectAnswer == 0) Answer1Correct = YES;
    else if(indexOfCorrectAnswer == 1) Answer2Correct = YES;
    else if(indexOfCorrectAnswer == 2) Answer3Correct = YES;
    else if(indexOfCorrectAnswer == 3) Answer4Correct = YES;
}
```

And here is how I have my text file.

```
Question on the first line
Answer
Answer
Answer
Answer
* Correct Answer that is displayed separately

Next question goes here
Answer
Answer
Answer
Answer
* Correct Answer that is displayed separately
```

Each text file has approx 200+ questions in it.

Comment: How about creating an INT as a class property and use it as your counter. Copy your text file questions into an array and +1 the counter every time you display a question so you can access the next item in your array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have a restriction to use a Text File but on iOS I recommend you to use plist, The operation system knows how to manage it well and also it is very easy to edit.

Comment: I only know how to use a plist with table view and it doesn't work well with my GUI

Comment: @JoeMarion weird. plist is the way to work on local data with iOS. Maybe you could share some code and I could help in this...In any case I suggest you to learn how to use plist, it would probably be a lot easier then truing to make the text file work...

Comment: https://github.com/JoeMarion/Tacp-Quiz-master
I am still very new to Objective C that is just a way that I have slowly been trying to figure it out. Here is my code without four of the five categories.

Comment: @JoeMarion Wow! You must work with plist. The text files are too problematic& complex. Try this one, if that won't help I'll try to code some to help: http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/05/30/property-list-tutorial-using-plist-to-store-user-data/

Comment: I originally was using a plist but I need to be able to show an incorrect/correct screen along with the correct answer in between each question. Actually, I used a switch first that was enormous, but thats another story and a reason why the code is a little unorganized because it has changed so many times. With a plist I was only able to run through all the questions and it changed the way that the app looks too much.

Comment: @JoeMarion I don't think coding the app logic into the DB file is a good way to go. It's a bad thing to do...If I understood you.

Comment: I think you do understand. This has been mostly a learning project for me and I do want to learn the proper way to do it. I just don't know how to use a plist and maintain the answer screen as well.

Comment: I am really just trying to understand a good way to implement this where I can wrap my head around what is happening. Building this so far has taught me a lot. I was using a switch, which was a bad idea, and then someone who I actually got to talk to suggested the text file way.

Comment: @JoeMarion Not sure I understand completely, but why not just give a serial number to each question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that might help you out. First create a class to hold the questions. Here is the code.
    //Question.h
    #import

```
@interface Question : NSObject
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *answers;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *question,*answer;
-(id)init;
-(void)addAnswer:(NSString *)param;
@end

//Question.m
#import "Question.h"

@implementation Question
@synthesize question,answer,answers;
-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"Question created");
        answers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        return self;
    }
    else return nil;
}
-(void)addAnswer:(NSString *)param{
    [answers addObject:param];
}
@end
```

Now in your view controller add these lines

```
    NSUInteger numberOfOccurrences = [[content componentsSeparatedByString:@"*"] count] - 1;

    NSMutableArray *questions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i<numberOfOccurrences; i++) {
        [questions addObject:[[Question alloc] init]];
    }
    BOOL addingNewQuestion=YES;
    BOOL addingAnswer=NO;

    int questionIndex=0;

    for(NSString *line in lines) {
        NSLog(@"%@",line);
        if (addingNewQuestion) {
            [[questions objectAtIndex:questionIndex] setQuestion:line];
            addingNewQuestion=NO;
            addingAnswer=YES;
        }
        else if(addingAnswer){
            if ([line isEqualToString:@""]) {
                NSLog(@"Adding new question");
                addingNewQuestion=YES;
                addingAnswer=NO;
                questionIndex++;
            }
            else if([[line substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"*"]){
                NSLog(@"Adding correct answer");
                [[questions objectAtIndex:questionIndex] setAnswer:[line substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, line.length - 2)]];
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Adding answer");
                [[questions objectAtIndex:questionIndex] addAnswer:line];
            }
        }
    }
```

Right now you have an array called questions and each member is a question object with its own question, answer array and correct answer. You could access each question with a for loop like this.

```
for(int i = 0;i<[questions count];i++){
    [self handleQuestion:[questions objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

I did not write the handleQuestion method. Do whatever you like there.